# SQL query using Group By and Having

Tags: sql

I'm working with [this table](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/Read_the_notes_about_this_table.) and I couldn't find how to answer this question about it:

> List the continents that have a total population of at least 100
>   million.

How can I "list" continents and calculate the SUM of population over each continent. I did some trials but got syntax errors.
like:

```
SELECT continent from world
HAVING SUM(population) > = 100000000
```

Comment: `HAVING` is used when you have a `GROUP BY`clause and you are trying to filter based on one of the grouping fields so include `GROUP BY` clause

Comment: Just add Group By clause before Having clause

Comment: Who suggested you to add `GROUP BY` in the question but not in the query ?? It's confusing that you really don't know how to write the desired query.

Comment: I did multiple trials, first with GROUP BY and HAVING, both of them, but just copied one last one of my trials after having all others refused :). What do you mean by confusing? @Cookie Monster thank you! I think that is my fault I added Group By after the clause Having. didn't know that it makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have `GROUP BY` clause to use `HAVING` clause.

The modified query will be

```
SELECT
    continent,
    SUM(population) AS total_population
FROM world
GROUP BY continent
HAVING SUM(population) >= 100000000
```

- [REFERENCE - 1](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp)
- [REFERENCE - 2](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-having-clause.htm)

Comment: This checks if population of each continent is greater than 100m?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT continent,SUM(population) as population 
FROM world
GROUP BY continent
HAVING SUM(population) > = 100000000
```